# ответ на ajax запрос возвращается с двоеточием

Tags: json, сервер

Здравствуй, сообщество.
Ситуация следующая. При ajax запросе ответ от сервера приходит как минимум в 2 строках, где первая строка это всегда двоеточие ":". Пытался найти ответ в просторах интернета но ничего похожего не нашел. Возможно не докопал... Почему так происходит и с чем это может быть связано? Как лечиться?
На локальной машине ответы приходят нормально, т.е. без двоеточий.

PHP 7.0.30, nginx 1.10.3

Comment: Уважаемый, а что за сервер, какой язык на нем? Возможно на нём каких-то данных не хватает или он вам что-то лишнее передаёт? По идее нужно в его код смотреть.

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: PHP 7.0.30, nginx 1.10.3.
на сервере приложение работает давно и так то проблем нет, тикает как швейцарские часы. проблема именно ajax запросах. Сейчас замечено что куски html он возвращает корректно, а вот на такое
echo '123'  или echo json_encode(['123']) возвращается вот так
1 строка - :
2 строка - 123

Comment: Коля, тебе надо код сервера смотреть и там копать. Клиентский запрос не при чем. Послал запрос к серверу - получил ответ. И то, что в ответе - формирует сервер. И не важно, что на сервере работает - wp, laravel, django или просто `mail.php`. Изучай код сервера.

Comment: Максим, спасибо за ответ. Есть админы для этого у нас. Теперь знаю кого нужно доставать

Answer (score 0):

Такое поведение оказалось причиной обновления сервера, конкретнее apach2 и php. К сожалению нет данных по версиям, админы не предоставили. После отката версий на предыдущие, все стало на свои места.